fuel filter all sensors and now I'm leaking gas as soon as I pump it in the tank I've done everything that has been recommended and it still does the
2003 Buick rendezvous replaced heater core thermostat gas lines fuel filter a couple sensors rpm up n down stalls at stop signs new gaslines now my gas tank losing gas on the top of tank I've done everything that has been recommended and it still not running or drivable please help I have kids grandkids and I'm walking to work please thank you.
-

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please don't double post questions. If you have new information to add, you can edit your original question.
